# Problema al crear cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Estoy tratando de crear un contador de visitas para saver si un usuario ya visito un post con **cookies** para llevar un count de los post que los usuarios visitan en mi web , la manera que estoy implementando esto es atraves de los enlaces es decir cada ves que un usuario clickea para ver un post lo lleva a otra pagina en la cual estoy creando la **cookie** ejemplo:

```
<!--enlace que lleva al post -->

<a href="visitas.php?id=9"> Titulo del post</a>
```

en las **visitas.php**

```
 $idPost=$_GET["id"];//capturar id del post
 setcookie("view",$idPost,strtotime( '+30 days' ),"/",false, false);
 $cookieValue=$_COOKIE['view'];//valor de la cookie


 //verificar cookie 

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['view'])){

        echo"Cookie no creada";//siempre entra aqui

    }else{

        echo"Cookie Value :".$cookieValue
      }
```

alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal ya he creado cookie antes con login y me funcionan perfectamente pero ahora al tratar de crear este contador de visitas no logro mi objetivo con las cookies

Comment: Hay un límite de 4093 *bytes* **por dominio** para el almacen de *cookies* en el navegador. ¿ Lo has tenido en cuenta ? [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/640938/8663418)

Comment: no creo que alla excedido   a esa cantidad

Comment: Era para hacerte ver que igual ese método no te vale en *el mundo real*; tus usuarios solo podrán *recordar* un limitado número de articulos visitados.